# How to setup conditional validator for RadioButtonList then textbox in C# (webforms)?

Tags: c#, validation, webforms, textbox, radiobuttonlist

I have a RadioButtonList that includes three values:
- UPC
- Description
- ItemCode

UPC can only allow numbers (0-9).
Description can allow any text.
ItemCode only allows numbers or letters.

I have a textbox (txtbox_reportBy).

Is there a way to setup three types of validators all for the same textbox based on which radiobutton value is selected?

i.e.
If UPC is selected, then the textbox's validator should only allow numbers.
If Description is selected, then the textbox's validator probably don't have to validate anything.
If ItemCode is selected, then the textbox's validator should only allow numbers or letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression validator. On change of the radiobuttonlist, change the validation expression and possibly ErrorMessage to something applicable to the selection.